# Managing memory in Postgres and C

Tags: c, postgresql

I'm getting a documentation about SPI interfaces (in Postgres) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/spi-interface.html

1. Does SPI_finish() cleans up after itself automatically (as far as i understood, that no, only if you're cancel transaction via elog(ERROR))?
2. Also, how to catch "cancel request" when using SPI? (because I think that I have hang sessions and they load memory)

Comment: This question needs more detail AND more focus.

Comment: Okay, question: ctrl + c - cancel request, SPI works and postgres process closes fine, ctrl+z - postgres process doesn't close. What to do? (should I switch to libpq?)

Comment: Ctrl+Z stops a process, but doesn't kill it.

Comment: okay, then what's the difference between simple query in postgres (like select * from blablabla) and C function with SPI, if ctrl+z works fine on queries?

Comment: Ctrl+Z will not cancel a query on my Fedora Linux system. Don't add comments, [edit] your question and add all detail necessary to understand what you are trying to do and what your problem is.